# i3 GTK & Qt theming problem

Tags: window-manager, i3, gtk, qt, tiling-wm

Applications that use Qt and GTK look different how can I fix this, i’m using i3 is there any software to theme Qt?

PS: I’ve heard about lxappearance but it only works for GTK

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to include more details. _In what way_ do you want to fix this? Do you want your Qt applications to look like GTK applications, or vice versa, or both to adhere to a third graphics standard?